# Finding anomalies or deviation in a dataframe. Comparing mean and stand deviations via plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I have collected data by crawling web pages and collected script hashes and depth of them. I have converted the data into a pandas dataframe.

**Goal**
As part of my research, I would like to do some statistical measures and find how the depth behaves in each group of hashes.

2) I had calculated the group standard deviation of depth using std() function. But not sure how to compare that to standard deviation of the group of hashes.

3) Also calculated the mean for each group of hashes. Would like to know how to have a separate column which show the difference between the group mean and the actual value.. would like to know how to plot these two columns.(The new column and plotting applies to question 2 also).

If there are any novel methods to identify outliers or deviations, would like to know them also.

Data:

```
       FileHash      Depth
0         A            1
1         A            2
2         C            1
3         B            1
4         C            3
5         A            5
6         C            2
7         A            0
```

I tried to find the best fitting distribution fitter and found gennorm to be the best one.

I had also tried finding outliers using modified z-score.

For question 3, I am expecting output like this:

```
     FileHash      Depth  MeanDeviation
0      A             1       -1
1      A             2        0
2      C             1       -1
3      B             1        0
4      C             3        1
5      A             5        3
6      C             2        0
7      A             0       -2
```

Comment: Thanks @Brendan for the edit :thumbsup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work for what you need?

```
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# your data 
df = pd.DataFrame({'FileHash': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A'], 'Depth': [1,2,1,1,3,5,2,0]})


mean_dev = df.Depth - df.groupby('FileHash').Depth.transform('mean')
df.assign(MeanDeviation=mean_dev)
```

outputs

```
   FileHash       Depth    MeanDeviation
0      A             1       -1
1      A             2        0
2      C             1       -1
3      B             1        0
4      C             3        1
5      A             5        3
6      C             2        0
7      A             0       -2
```

and

```
df.plot(use_index=False, y=['Depth','MeanDeviation'])
```

plots a comparison of depth and MeanDeviation.

*Note:*
I am not sure what you mean by

> not sure how to compare that to standard deviation of the group of
>   hashes

since a single observation cannot have a standard deviation. Standard deviation is only a measure for a group of values.

Comment: I think I can try the same on standard deviation. I was missing the transform command.

Comment: A small correction to your code, the assigning function doesn't add the new column to original dataframe.

you can use

`df= df.assign(MeanDeviation=mean_dev)`

otherwise, while plotting , error occurs--> MeanDeviation not in index.

Comment: I am interested what you mean since the standard deviation, by definition, applies only to the group of data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation. Do you mean you will compare each datum's z score with the SD?

Thank you for catching that with the reassignment. I have notice that many posts on this site take the convention of not assigning the desired output to any variable, which is consistent with how one would use Jupyter notebook. As I do not often use Jupyter, I make a lot of mistakes with this convention.

Comment: Yes, Standard deviation applies to the group. So for Std.dev. instead of the mean in above code you mentioned, I changed it to apply standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zackg22